# Complex valued function whick makes several loops of different sizes in positive half-plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to build complex-valued function $f(z)$ with the following properties:

1. $|f(z)|\le0$
2. $f(z)=1$ if $arg(z)=2 \pi n$, $n \in Z$ (crosses one on each n-th loop)
3. $f(z)=0$ if $arg(z)=2 \pi m$, $m \in Z \neq n \in Z$ (crosses zero on each loop with other integer numbers)
4. $0 < |f(z)| < 1$ if $\frac{arg(z)}{2\pi} \notin Z$ (does not cross neither $0$ nor $1$ except whole loop)

The plot for $n=3$ should look like below:

[image]

Sorry, this is continuous curve, which goes exact :)

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed explanation of what you're asking for? In particular, please take into account the following remarks:

1. Your first condition implies $f \equiv 0$. 

2. $\arg z$ only ranges from $- \pi$ to $\pi$, so $\arg z = 2 \pi m$ is never possible for $m \neq 0$, unless you mean argument branches which gets weird and demands thorough explanation. 

3. If a holomorphic function $f(z)$ is constant for fixed $\arg z$ (e.g. $f(z) = 1$ whenever $\arg z = 2 \pi n$ as you wish), then $f(z)$ must be constant everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Nephroid of Freeth, which is nominally given by

$$r=a\left(1+2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right),\quad \theta\in[0,4\pi]$$

I have modified it as follows to make it look like your picture (see below; here $a=1/3$)

$$r=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right),\quad \theta\in[0,4\pi]\\
z=-re^{-i\theta}
$$

This can generalized to create more complex figures by choosing

$$r=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+2\sin\frac{\theta}{n}\right),\quad \theta\in[0,2n\pi]\\
z=-re^{-i\theta}
$$

[image]